# Rotating Point feature problem

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, features

I am trying to create new symbols for our Stormwater Stream Restoration dept.. Utilizing some of the ESRI came symbols, I have adjusted their size and color and added them to the map. When I click the Rotate tool, it shows the feature rotating in the preview as I turn it, but when I let go of the mouse, the screen blinks, but the symbol never rotated. Also, when I'm in Symbology/Advance/Rotation, the only options in the drop down are: *None, Random, and expression.
Btw... I don't know how to code or write any scripts yet.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you need a field in the attribute table of the feature with a data type of Double. You can call it Rotation or something. This is where the value is stored when you use the rotate tool. Then that field should show in the Symbology/Advance/Rotation drop down.

Comment: Awesome... worked perfectly! I don't understand why almost all of the tutorials I read on it never mentioned adding a field with a data type of double. Thanks for your help!